# geom_bar width in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating faceted barchart with ggplot. I have the problem that the MWE below generates the graph at the bottom. I would like it to generate bars that have the same widths in both facets. How would I go about this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)),
                y = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2));

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ g);
```

[image: problematic image]

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196143/bars-in-geom-bar-have-unwanted-different-widths-when-using-facet-wrap

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you need. Creating a place holder for the missing factor level using the `complete` function from `tidyr` package can also make the bar width the same at two facets. The downside is that the second plot is imblanced.

```
ggplot(tidyr::complete(df, x, g), aes(x = 1, y = y, fill = x)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
       facet_wrap(~ g);
```

[image]