# How to get rid of wider bars of a ggplot2 plot with geom_bar() in cases of count=0

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here is my `data.frame()`:

```
df <- data.frame(Round = rep(c("A", "B", "C" ),150), Group = rep(c("UP", "DOWN"),75),Task = rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5"),30), V2 = sample(c(0,1,2), 50, replace = T), V1 = sample(c(0,1,2), 50, replace = T))
dfmelt <- melt(df)
```

I am trying to plot a `facet_grid` like this:

```
b <- ggplot(data=dfmelt, aes(x=value, fill=variable))
b <- b + geom_bar(stat="count", position = "dodge", width = 0.9)
b <- b + facet_grid(Group ~ Task, scales = "free")
```

, which produces the following:

[image]

I want to get rid of the wider columns, such as `V1 at the position 0 of T1-UP`, `V1 at the position 1 of T5-DOWN` and `V2 at the position 0 of T3-UP`.

The problem occur when the `count` of one of my variables (let's say V1) in a given `x` position (0,1, or 2) is equal to `0` and the other variable (V2) is greater than `0`. In this case, the V2 bar becomes wider to fill the whole `x` position.

I have tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101512/the-same-width-of-the-bars-in-geom-barposition-dodge) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883652/geom-bar-width-in-ggplot2) solutions with no success. **Is there a way to make the bars have a fixed width?**

Comment: @Henrik I tried this one too. No success.

Comment: @AlcemirSantos Note that Psidom's answer uses the same work-around as the [second question you said you tried and didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37884158/903061) (which is also answered by Psidom!), and the concept is identical to Henrik's suggested dupe. I'm not sure this question/answer adds anything not well-covered in the dupes.

Comment: I notice, as said in comment to @Psidom, it solves the problem but it is still a workaround. Perhaps, it is not the best solution, which is why I think might justify the question, or not?

Comment: In his reply to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1776, Hadley says: _That's how dodging works. You might want to try facetting instead._ BTW, this issue has been adressed already several times on SO: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12806260/3817004) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15367762/3817004), e.g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to implement the count manually outside `ggplot`, and fill missing data with NA with `tidyr::complete` and then do an *identity* bar plot:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)
dfmelt_count <- dfmelt %>% 
        count(Group, Task, variable, value) %>% 
        complete(Group, Task, variable, value)

b <- ggplot(data=dfmelt_count, aes(x=value, y = n, fill=variable))
b <- b + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.9)
b <- b + facet_grid(Group ~ Task, scales = "free")
b
```

[image]

Comment: This worked as a workaround.  Would you know to explain why the "stat=count" doesn't produce such output?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is going on underhood. But most likely the `count` status is doing the same thing as `dplyr::count`, i.e, missing values are implicit, so, if V2 == 0, then there is no such row as V2 in the result, this makes ggplot think there is no value there and thus keep no place holder for that value. With `complete` function, if `V2 == 0`, it will still have row `V2` there but with count of `NA`, so when plotting, there will be a place holder for V2 even though the count for it is zero.