# ggplot binwidth in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about the binwidth in ggplot in r.

I have two sets of data, one called "error_hat" and one called "error_tilde". I have made their histogram separately, and I see they are similar to each other.

[image]

[image]

Now I want to put them together to make a comparison. My code is as followed:

```
catagory <- c(rep("error_hat",length(error_hat)) , rep("error_tilde",length(error_tilde)))

error <- c(error_hat, error_tilde)

error_data<-data.frame(catagory,error)

ggplot(error_data, aes(x=error,group=catagory,fill=catagory))+
  geom_histogram(position="dodge2", binwidth=0.03)+theme_bw()
```

It produces a picture like this:

[image]

I am wondering why the data in the middle has a different width (since I have set all the width to be 0.03)?

Could anyone help me with this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: `binwidth` doesn't refer to the width of the bars as they appear on the chart, it refers to how your data is "binned" into groups to make a histogram. So `binwidth = 0.03` means that, for example, values from 0 - 0.03 will be counted up to make one bar, and values from 0.03-0.06 will be counted up to make the 2nd bar, and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bars in geom\_bar are not of equal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048925/bars-in-geom-bar-are-not-of-equal-width)

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of using `dodge2` versus `dodge`. This is the expected behavior as outlined [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html).

Maybe you want regular `dodge` instead?

```r
library(ggplot2)
#fake data that mimics yours
set.seed(42)
error_hat <- runif(100)
error_tilde <- runif(100)
catagory <- c(rep("error_hat",length(error_hat)) , rep("error_tilde",length(error_tilde)))
error <- c(error_hat, error_tilde)
error_data<-data.frame(catagory,error)
ggplot(error_data, aes(x=error,group=catagory,fill=catagory))+
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", binwidth=0.03)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>